# keyboard event generation question

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have to send a keyboard event from my console app with character code `nChar` and event code `nFlags`:
`SendKeyboardEvent(UINT nChar, UINT nFlags)`

For MFC dialog this function would be mapped to some event handler so I wouldn't have to worry about `nFlags` at all. Can someone point me to how I could obtain that value for the console app?

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to know. Do you want to know Win32 API to send a keyboard event or are you specifically interested in knowing what possible values nFlags can have?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to simulate the keyboard in another application, the function you should be using is SendInput() or at least keybd_event(). Keep in mind you have to set the focus window first or else your input won't go where you expected.

SendInput() : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310